# Data Integragration with Pentaho Kettle

Tags: database, pentaho, kettle, data-integration

I have three input components:

1. Excel Input
2. XML Input
3. Table Input

I would like to do some validation and verification before inserting the integrated data into a data base.

Which component should I use for the data transformation/verification?

Comment: What sort of validation and verification you need to perform?

Comment: I need to get the data for the same ID from the three sources and check consistency; for example, verify that the guy with ID 1 in source 1 and the guy with ID 1 in source 2 have the same address.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [Data Validator](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Data+Validator) step in PDI. Here you can validate the rows that are coming in from the Input step either using the inbuilt validator or even using regular expressions.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several aproaches to achieve the verification. The easiest one is to code your validations using the "Modified java script value" step, but it's the most resource hungry, so Pentaho recommends avoiding it if you can. So you can use others steps, like the ones under the "flow" category.